# JPA Entity Mapping which is related based on two other entity mappings

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

Not sure if this is possible but trying to map `WorkflowInstancePlayer player`  which is related based on two other entity mappings, `WorkActionClass` and `WorkflowInstance` in the entity below.

```
public class Action implements Serializable {
@Id
private Long action_id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "work_action_class_id", referencedColumnName = "work_action_class_id")
private WorkActionClass workActionClass;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "workflow_instance_id", referencedColumnName = "workflow_instance_id")
private WorkflowInstance workflowInstance;

UPDATE: How can I map to a WorkflowInstancePlayer player?????
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumns( {
        @JoinColumn(name = "workflow_instance_id", referencedColumnName = "workflow_instance_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "workActionClass.role_class_id", referencedColumnName = "role_class_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
 private WorkflowInstancePlayer player;
```

The workflowInstancePlayer is derived based on `workflow_instance_id` and `role_class_id` but `role_class_id` is really an attibute of `workActionClass` mapped above `(workActionClass.role_class_id)`

```
public class WorkflowInstancePlayer implements Serializable {
@Id
private WorkflowInstance workflowInstance;

@Id
private RoleClass roleClass;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "badge", referencedColumnName = "badge")
private Employee employee;
```

```
public class WorkActionClass implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "trx_seq")
private Long work_action_class_id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "role_class_id")
private RoleClass roleClass;
```

Example data would be:

```
Action
------
Id = 10
work_action_class_id = 7
workflow_instance_id = 2


WorkActionClass
---------------
Id = 7
role_name = reviewer
role_class_id = 3


WorkflowInstancePlayer
----------------------
workflow_instance_id = 2
role_class_id = 3
badge = 111222
```

So in the Action Entity, I'll know the Workflow Instance Player is Employee with Id 111222 without actually storing the badge in the Action table.

## UPDATE

Based on Vlad's post I tweaked it to be

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
   @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="(SELECT a.role_class_id FROM (Use Table Name not Entity Name here) a WHERE a.work_action_class_id = work_action_class_id)", referencedColumnName="role_class_id")),
   @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name="workflow_instance_id", referencedColumnName="workflow_instance_id"))
})
```

Comment: badge = 111222 is some function of workflow_instance_id( = 2) and role_class_id ( = 3) - is that correct?.... if not how do you derive badge = 111222?

Comment: not really. This is a workflow application. Employee 111222 was assigned as the Reviewer with in the workflow.  The reviewer will have many actions depending on the workflow type.  The Oracle sequence number of 2 was next inline for the workflow instance id and a Reviewer Role has a role_class_id of 3.  So those three values get inserted into  WorkflowInstancePlayer

Comment: @NickJI I reread your comment.  if you mean function as in "a relationship" then yes.  At first I read it as "a formula"  as in instance_id times role_class_id divided by.... etc.  The relationship is defined in the WorkflowInstancePlayer table

Comment: to get to Employee you need to get to WorkflowInstancePlayerId but coming from either RoleClass or WorkflowInstance, so you'll need to traverse a one-to-many - with nothing to tell you which is the correct WorkflowInstancePlayerId - so I don't think that particualr approach would work.

Comment: what is a work around?  I was thinking @Transient and then manually mapping??

Comment: You can have somethin like this.... (see next comment also)   @Transient
private Employee actionOwnerUser;

Public Employee getActionOwnerUser()
return actionOwnerUser;

Public void setActionOwnerUser()
//your manual mapping code
actionOwnerUser = //your manual mapping code

Comment: From what I understand you will have the  Employee info  when the employee is actually assigned to a workflow, but without the action_owner_badge join you will have no way to get to this on future calls. So although setting up the @Transient variable is possible when the workflow is introduced to the system, you are not persisting the link between Action and Employee so will not be able to populate actionOwnerUser at a future date... depending on your business requriements that might not be a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this mapping:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(
    name = "workflow_instance_id", 
    referencedColumnName = "workflow_instance_id",
    insertable = false, 
    updatable = false
)
private WorkflowInstance workflowInstance;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumnOrFormula(
    formula = @JoinFormula(
            value="(SELECT a.work_action_class_id FROM WorkActionClass a WHERE a.role_class_id = role_class_id)", 
        referencedColumnName = "work_action_class_id"
    )
)
private WorkActionClass workActionClass;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns( {
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "workflow_instance_id", 
        referencedColumnName = "workflow_instance_id"),
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "role_class_id", 
        referencedColumnName = "role_class_id")
})
private WorkflowInstancePlayer player;
```

Comment: your @JoinColumnOrFormula has helped out.  See my post, I believe the formula should be on the WorkflowInstancePlayer mapping.  Things compile and my tables look to be created as expected but now I get ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery when retrieving.

Comment: Great. For that error, make the association LAZY and make sure you don't JOIN FETCH it, to allow Hibernate to retrieve it with a secondary query.

Comment: hmm I did click and upvoted, then added my comment.  The comment submit in IE hung so I copied to clipboard, refreshed page and pasted it again.  The upvote must have timedout too.  Let me try LAZY and see if we can close this Q out

Comment: Thanks. I hope it can help.

Comment: Nice.  on WorkflowInstancePlayer I added @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY).  I had to modify the joinformula to use the actual table name instead of the Entity "SELECT a.role_class_id FROM WF_WORK_ACTION_CLASS" vs "SELECT a.role_class_id FROM WorkActionClass" and it works.  Thanks!